# Is there a way to versionate Vue frontend, and check with backend if it's the latest version?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm making SPAs with Laravel and VueJs.
Sometimes .js files from fronted are cached in the browser, and the client is not seeing the latest updates. I'm using chunk names but the are still cached by the browser.

Is there a way to versionate the files automatically with Webpack and notice the client to correctly update the site?

Update > webpack.mix.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const webpack = require('webpack')

// const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')

mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist/css')
  .styles([
    'resources/assets/sass/fa/css/fontawesome-all.css',
    'public/css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css',
    'public/css/inspinia.css',
    'node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css'
  ], 'public/dist/css/all.css')

  .sourceMaps()
  //.disableNotifications()

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version()

  mix.extract([
    'vue',
    'vform',
    'axios',
    'vuex',
    'jquery',
    'popper.js',
    'vue-i18n',
    'vue-meta',
    'js-cookie',
    'vue-router',
    'sweetalert2',
    'vuex-router-sync',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome',
    '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
  ])
}

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js')
    }
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
    publicPath: '/wms/public/'
  }

})
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel Mix to compile your assets (`webpack.mix.js` as config)?

Comment: Yes using this output setting for the chunks:
chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].[chunkhash].js',

Comment: Can you add the complete code of `webpack.mix.js` to your question?

Comment: Actually you should already be seeing versioned assets, at least if you run a production build (see `mix.version()`). If there is a `mix-manifest.json` in your `public/` directory and you still have cache issues, I'm not able to help.

Comment: You are using the `mix('app.js')` asset helper in your blade templates instead of `asset('app.js')`, right? Only `mix()` will load the assets through `mix-manifest.json` and therefore bust caches...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that difference